# I'm trying to figure out how to add two validation rules to One SharePoint list

Tags: validation, column-validation

I'm trying to figure out how to add two validation rules to One SharePoint list.

1. If the user selects 'Risk' from the 'Risk/Issue?' column, then they must not leave the 'Risk Mitigation Plan' field blank.

'Risk/Issue?' Column is a drop down menu,  Risk Mitigation Plan is a multiple line text field

2. If the user selects 'Closed' from the 'Status' column then the must not leave the 'Closed Date' field blank

The 'Status' field is a drop down menu  and the 'Closed Date' field is a date picker

What formula would help me accomplish this?  Thank you!

--I can change the field types if that helps

Screen shot of the list & validation I'm trying to Implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're able to use js/jQuery but below is a way to accomplish this using code.

```
var status = $("select[title='Status']").val();
var closedDate = $("input[title='Closed Date']").val().length;

function PreSaveAction(){
   if(status == "Closed" && closedDate == 0){
      return False;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use multiline text in formula. If you can convert mitigation plan to a single line of text then below formula should work, assuming your other dropdowns fields are choice fields.

Navigate to List -> List Settings -> Validation Settings. Use below formula and add an appropriate error message in 'user message' field.

```
IF([Risk]="Risk",IF(NOT(ISBLANK([MitigationPlan])),TRUE,FALSE),IF([Closed]="Closed",IF(NOT(ISBLANK([ClosedDate])),TRUE,FALSE),TRUE))
```